# Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error - Not able to complete NVIDIA Tesla P100 Grid Setup on the vSphere Host Server with Vmware ESXI 6.7

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, nvidia

I am unable to setup the `NVIDIA Tesla P100` Grid Setup on the `vSphere` Host Server with `Vmware ESXI 6.7` on `DELL EMC poweredge R740`.

When I am trying to run `nvidia-smi` command I am getting following error

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
```

NVIDIA Driver as follows

```
#esxcli software vib list |grep -i nvidia 
NVIDIA-VMware_ESXi_6.7_Host_Driver 390.113-1OEM.670.0.0.8169922 NVIDIA VMwareAccepted 2019-03-06
```

And it also showing as module loaded in the OS as below

```
# vmkload_mod -l | grep nvidia
nvidia 0 13828
```

Also we done following changes in BIOS

```
Memory Mapped I/O above 4 GB - Enabled
Memory Mapped I/O above Base - 512 GB
```

**Host OS : Vmware ESXI 6.7**

**NVIDIA Graphics Hardware : Tesla P100**

Kindly help me to solve this issue

Comment: Have you passed it through to a VM?

Comment: @Chopper3 No, when I am trying nvidia-smi in esxi shell at hosting server for nvidia device details at that point getting the mentioned error. I can give Tesla p100 GPU card as fully dedicated PCI devices (not shared ) to VM, but as shared GPU not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself. I have found the solution from an [online resource](https://citrixguyblog.com/2017/07/25/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver/#more-1506).
As, it is said in the above mentioned resource, to solve this problem, I had to disable the `DirectPath I/O` on the host .

The fix provided in the above mentioned resource is as follows.

> You need to disable the “DirectPath I/O” on the host. Navigate to
>   Hardware –> PCI Devices . Make sure the graphic card is not selected
>   as passtrough device.  Thanks to Simon Schaber from NVIDIA who gave me
>   the final clue.